# How to tunnel through HTTP proxy?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, tunnel

Hi my ISP uses proxy authentication to log on to the internet so many of my apps won't work. Is there a way to tunnel all traffic so they're able to connect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a workplace ISP?  If so, check with your IT department for approved VPN solutions, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a product like [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com), it will intercept your app's connections and pipe them through a tunneling http proxy, or SOCKS server.